# Best way to design a table in which a cell has mutiple references?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, database-design, data-modeling

My question regards how to design a database.

I have one table, called posts, with columns:

```
ID, subject, keywords, (and a few other columns)
```

and another table called keywords with:

```
kw_id, keyword.
```

Now, each "post" has several keywords and, sometimes, keywords are deleted because they don't make sense or are duplicates.

My question is:

- Can ***keywords*** column in table ***posts*** be a foreign key? (each row will have multiple keywords)
- If I can't, what is the best way to ensure data integrity (specially when a keyword is deleted)?

thanks in advance

EDIT: Can you point me any books or documents I should read about database design? It seems I'm laking key knowledge about database design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must flip dependencies: Table KEYWORD should reference back to post. You may want someting in between to find all posts for a given keyword (pseudo code):

```
POST
    POST_ID
    ...

KEYWORD
    KEYWORD_ID
    NAME        /* the keyword */

POSTKEYWORDREL    /* relationship */
    POST_ID     /* foreign key to POST */
    KEYWORD_ID  /* foreign key to KEYWORD */
```

Now you can easily delete a keyword from a given post by just removing the relationship in `POSTKEYWORDREL`.

EDIT: As always, for documentation let me point you to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design). You should also have a look at [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) (in my opinion the most important concept when it comes to database design).

Comment: @Tivie: Two Wikipedia links added to the answer, you can deeper dive into the problem from there. Keep in mind that the given 'keyword' design may become much more complex in reality, e.g. when it comes to multi-language support.

Comment: Thanks, this will help me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You need a many-many table in the "middle" with foreign keys

Posts:

```
ID (PK)
Subject
(and a few other columns)
```

Keywords:

```
kw_id (PK)
Keyword (UQ)
```

PostsKeywords

```
PostID (PK, FK to Posts.ID)
kw_id (PK, FK to Keywords.kw_id)
```

Why have different conventions for your "ID" columns though? Personally I'd use PostID and KeywordID throughout.

Edit: [database design link](http://www.geeksengine.com/database/design/index.php)

Comment: thanks. Actually, in the first table its called p_id, i forgot the "p".

Answer (score 1):

to follow your design, in the posts table you remove the column keywords.

you create then another table to make the many-to-many relationship, something like

PostKeywords

that table will contain at minimum post_Id and kw_id and both are foreign keys to their own tables.

personally in these cases I also create a local PK column that is not involved in the many to many, for example a PostKeywords_ID which is an auto increment local to that table only.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting a **keyword** column in your **post** table, you'll be wanting a separate table **post_keyword** with two columns: **post_id** and **keyword_id**.  The presence of a row in this table indicates that a particular **post** has been assigned a particular **keyword**. The primary key of this table is (**post_id**, **keyword_id**).  Both columns are foreign keys to their master tables.

This is standard design practice for many-to-many relationships.

If your **keyword** items are to be presented in a particular order, add an **order** column.

For best results, by the way, name the id column **post_id** in your **post** table and all the other tables in which it appears. That way various schema-engineering tools will be able to figure out what you're doing.

Comment: I use underscores just because some of my stuff is in case-insensitive Oracle.  @gbn's suggested names for columns and tables are fine if you're only working in mySql.

Comment: thanks. I will be using a database in MySql for the website and a SQLite for the android app.